# TortoiseHG and hgsubversion (Windows): "no module named hgsubversion"

Tags: svn, tortoisehg, hgsubversion

I have installed the newest version of TortoiseHG for Windows from https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html (2.8.1)

I did

```
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion .
```

And have the correct path set in mercurial.ini:

```
[extensions]
hgsubversion = C:\hgextensions\hgsubversion\hgsubversion
```

If I do:

```
hg version --svn
```

I can see that hgsubversion seems to be installed correctly:

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.6.2)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2012 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

hgsubversion: 32f6b970c762
Subversion: 1.6.16
bindings: SWIG
```

But when I want to clone a SVN repository (any example from the web) it says:

```
abort: No module named hgsubversion!
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try to update hgsubversion to the c6e9889dba27 - it works for me.

Comment: This is harmful advice, because it means the hgsubversion maintainers don't get a bug report.

Comment: Harmful long term, but it sure got me out of a tight fix while a bug makes its way through a process!

Comment: The hgsubversion maintainers don't check all about hgsubversion questions on SO?

Answer (score 7):

Update|return to to latest tag of hgsubversion. And fill bug-report

Answer (score 0):

Starting from TortoiseHG 2.10 (current is 2.10.1)

```
>hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.8)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)
```

and HGSubversion 91cf81a36236 (r1100)

```
hgsubversion>hg id
91cf81a36236 tip
```

functionality was restored