# Hg convert to SVN gives "does not look like a Subversion repository"

Tags: svn, mercurial, mercurial-convert

This question pretty much the same as [HG Convert on SVN gives "does not look like a Subversion Repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784894/hg-convert-on-svn-gives-does-not-look-like-a-subversion-repository) , but solution given there did not work for me.

Even though I have local svn repository compatible with Subversion 1.7 (db format 4) I get this:

```
D:\Work>hg convert file:///D:\Work\pbr
assuming destination pbr-hg
initializing destination pbr-hg repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a CVS checkout
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a Git repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a Subversion repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr is not a local Mercurial repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a darcs repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a monotone repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a GNU Arch repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a Bazaar repository
file:///D:\Work\pbr does not look like a P4 repository
abort: file:///D:\Work\pbr: missing or unsupported repository
```

I have TortoiseHg 2.11 (with Mercurial 2.9) and TortoiseSVN 1.8.4 (Subversion 1.8.5) on Windows 8 Pro x64. I followed the steps here http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2013/12/26/converting-from-subversion-to-mercurial/

Tried to use SVN 1.5 repository format with db format 3 with same result.

I also tried to set up HGSubversion (not exactly sure if this will ) by cloning it from repository and enabling extension in %userprofile%\mercurial.ini as described in manual https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion

```
[extensions]
hgsubversion = D:\Work\hgsubversion
```

Couldn't get it working, here's what I got:

```
D:\Work>hg help hgsubversion
*** failed to import extension hgsubversion from D:\Work\hgsubversion: No module named hgsubversion
hg: unknown command 'hgsubversion'
Mercurial Distributed SCM
****
use "hg help" for the full list of commands or "hg -v" for details
```

As far as I understand though HGSubversion won't convert the svn repository (I do want to convert). I tried it because was listed as a possible solution in the other thread.

Please help me get this into Mercurial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reboot the system due software update and when I tried "hg convert" today it worked. So if anyone has the same issue, it's worth a try, maybe re-login could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but mentioned you HowTo's blog record contains ugly recipes **in core**:

- **If you have remote SVN-repository now, it will be better to process it for converting as remote repository (just because any version of SVN supported) - for HGSubversion**
- **If you still prefer local SVN-repository, preparing it with `svnrdump dump URL && svnadmin init && svnadmin load` is a lot faster and less tricky way, than establishing sync - for convert**

Unrelated notes:

- Pure forward-slashes are preferred in Mercurial commands, mixing back- and forward- in one command isn't good idea (while it is not a source of problem) `hg convert file:///D:/Work/pbr`
- For final converting SVN -> HG it will be better to have and use authormap in order to avoid such type of users

> Badger@614cc889-ef2e-2e4c-8acf-d1ad5db9eb81

in Mercurial-repo

- Error "No module named hgsubversion" [must be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679047/960558) a lot of time ago, try to sync your clone and update to tip

About topic

I can one more time confirm operability of solutions from mentioned by you topic in my environment (WinXP x86), can't test your OS-case

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

z:\>hg convert file:///z:/Old HG
initializing destination HG repository
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
0 Import

z:\>hg clone file:///z:/Old HG2
[r1] Badger: Import
pulled 1 revisions
updating to branch default
3 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
z:\>type z:\Old\db\format
4
layout sharded 1000
```

Comment: Ahh.. I had to restart pc due software update and was exactly the same thing that didn't work yesterday, did work today... So I guess one needs to restart (re-login?) after enabling "convert" extension. Before this I tried different HGSubversions revisions with no luck - cb4dccc90ff1 (tip), c6e9889dba27, 91cf81a36236 (mentioned in your linked thread as working).